# Is it possible to only have some parts of an app support an iPad view?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

We're looking to create an app that has 2 interfaces depending on what type of user logs in. The first user type (customer) will be using the app on their iPhone (almost exclusively) and the second user type (merchant) will be using it on their iPad (also almost exclusively). There are budget constraints preventing us from making both interfaces flexible to support both of these types of screen sizes.

What options do we have from a development perspective that allow us to create an experience that both of these user types will best benefit from? Do we need to submit 2 separate apps to the app store to achieve this or is there some other fancy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1588/_index.html)

> Important: It is strongly recommended that your iPad applications
>   support all orientations. This includes portrait, portrait
>   upside-down, landscape left and landscape right. **iPad apps that
>   require an orientation must support both variants of that orientation**.

Which basically means, if you want to support iPad, you have no other option than to allow both variants of a single orientation (atleast). This will make the UI easy to support both iPad and iPhone, however:

> depending on what type of user logs in.

The main question here is: Does your "merchant" run **strictly and only** on iPad? If so, then the clean way is probably to have 2 apps, that way you can control the content and code since you probably are showing different UI etc to your merchant/customers. If you have many differences in code and UI, you are best to go with 2 apps in my opinion.

However, no matter how you twist and turn, the ammount of work that needs to be taken into account for any option, depends on a list of other factors and can't be answered here, (would take a developer to go through your code/Design/project and estimate the work)

EDIT:

You have no "fancy" option to support 2 different devices and by any fancy methods choose who is allowed to use your app with what device after they have installed your product through App Store. Apple will and should reject that.

Comment: Legend. That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @SashaReid Great, glad to help ! GL

Answer (score 0):

Make it support for both iPad and iPhone Applications depending on user. If anyone enters from wrong platform detect and give a message to them.

**It also awareness your users that they are supposed to use iPad or iPhone only.**

And you can check the platform by using the code:

```
#define IDIOM    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()
#define IPAD     UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad

if ( IDIOM == IPAD ) {
    /* do something specifically for iPad. */
} else {
    /* do something specifically for iPhone or iPod touch. */
}
```

Comment: I have to downvote this answer, because doing as you describe will **get your app rejected instantly** . Please read the Apple documentations before giving tips on guidelines. If you mark your project to support both iPhone and iPad , you can not REJECT the usage of the app by code, that is not logical at all and is stricly against the Apple Guidelines.

Comment: could you please give more details. I didn't get you actually. Checking for platform or Support for both iphone and ipad.. Which one you think apple is going to reject?

Comment: You are not allowed to reject users from using your app using a device that you have specified that your project supports. You must have full functionality for the device that you specify as supported. If a user logs in to your app with an iPad and you kick him out/crash the app/message that he is not allowed to use the app based on device, your app will get rejected, that is common guidelines for Apple.

Comment: If we treat such users as incorrect login. How do apple will be able to identify?

Comment: They require you to provide demo accounts for logins. They will test the logins on multiple devices and review your app, and they have multiple other methods that nobody knows of only they know.